# Prove, that $L:=\{w\cdot d\cdot \overleftarrow{w}\mid w\in \{a,b\}^+\}$ is not regular using the pumping-lemma

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, regular-language, pumping-lemma

> Let $\Sigma =\{a,b,d\}$. Prove, that $L:=\{w\cdot d\cdot \overleftarrow{w}\mid w\in \{a,b\}^+\}$ is not regular over $\Sigma$.
>   Definition: $\overleftarrow{w}$ is defined inductively:$\overleftarrow{\lambda}:=\lambda,\; \overleftarrow{v\cdot x}:=x\cdot \overleftarrow{v}$, with $x\in\Sigma$ and $v\in\Sigma^*$

I know the basic idea of the pumping lemma got explained [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular), but I wouldn't know if my solution is correct, that's why I am asking for help regarding whether this proof of mine is correct or not.

---

Assume, $L$ is regular. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be the pumping-length and $w'=w\cdot d\cdot \overleftarrow{w}$ with ${\mid w\mid} = n$, $w'\in L$.

**EDIT: This is wrong, because $"d"$ is just one letter and not a word, I will edit it as soon as possible.**

No matter, how we partition $w'$ into 3 parts $w'=xyz$ with $x,y,z\in\Sigma^*$, we always have $x$ and $y$ only contain characters of word $w$, because ${\mid xy\mid}\leq n$.
Let ${\mid x\mid}=l$, ${\mid y\mid}=k$ and ${\mid z\mid}={\mid w\mid}-l-k+{\mid d\mid}+{\mid w\mid}$ with $l,k\in \mathbb{N}:l+k\leq n$.
For $i=2$, we have
$$xy^2z=l+2k+{\mid w\mid}-l-k+{\mid d\mid}+{\mid w\mid}$$, which is equal to $k+n+c+n$, where $k+n>n$, because $k>0$. That means, that ${\mid y+w\mid}>{\mid w\mid}$. Therefore, the first word $w$ contains more characters than $\overleftarrow{w}$, which means $xy^2z\notin L$.

Edit2: Because my first solution is wrong, here is a second thought:

Let $L$ be regular and $n$ be the pumping length. We choose $w=a^n\cdot d\cdot a^n$. Now we can show that this doesn't satisfy the pumping lemma similar to $L=\{a^nb^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ Is this ok?

Comment: What is $d$? A new letter? A fixed word?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Oh no, I made a mistake. The alphabet is $\Sigma = \{a,b,d\}$ and d is probably a letter then.

Comment: See my edit in answer to your edit2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is not correct, since it is only based on the length of words and does not depend on the alphabet. If it was correct, it would work for $\Sigma = \{a\}$ and prove that the language $L =\{w\cdot d\cdot \overleftarrow{w}\mid w\in \{a\}^+\}$, where $d$ is some fixed word of $a^*$, is not regular. But this language *is* regular.

**Edit**. In answer to your Edit2, yes, you can use this argument. More precisely, suppose that $L$ is regular, then $L \cap a^+da^+ = \{a^nda^n \mid n > 0\}$ would be regular and then you can use the pumping lemma to conclude that it is not the case.

Comment: I made a mistake. The alphabet contains $d$, that's why it should be a letter/character and not a word.